# jQuery Finding URL in div and opening in new tab?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor

I have jQuery selecting a anchor link in a div, and applying it to the entire div. I also want it to open in a new tab, how do I select both?

```
$(".client-item").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

This currently links the div, I just need to add target="_blank" somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of window.location, use:

```
var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
```

This will open in a tab, and focus on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/nKwV8/2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the link using `window.open`:

```
$(".client-item").click(function(){
     window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have a look at [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open);

```
window.open($(this).find("a").attr("href"),"name of your window","","width=400,height=200");
```